# Centering multiple images on a line

Tags: html, css, image, centering

So, I need to get 2 images next to each other, but centered. I've gotten to figure out how to center an image, but not how to center two of them. The problem is in the CSS with `display: block;`, and `display: inline-block;` doesn't work - it's as if it's simply inline.

My code to center one image:

CSS:

```
img     {
        margin: 0px auto;
        display: block;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>This Week's Photo Features</h1>
    <img src="images/photos/BarcelonaGraffiti.jpg">
    <img src="images/photos/BoulderButterfly.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS.

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <img src="images/photos/BarcelonaGraffiti.jpg">
  <img src="images/photos/BoulderButterfly.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are more-or-less correct, one solution is to put the images in a container and center the container:

```
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 220px; 
}
```

Here's a fiddle to better demonstrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/boa5rej1/

Answer (score -1):

Place both images in a container and center that container like this

```
<div align="center">
<img src="images/photos/BarcelonaGraffiti.jpg">
<img src="images/photos/BoulderButterfly.jpg">
</div>
```

You can use Almost any container you like.